# How do I create a new node with each loop in a for loop (swift/firebase)? It's only saving the last value

Tags: swift, loops, firebase, for-loop, firebase-realtime-database

I'm brand new to swift and still learning the basics. I have created a for loop to create a unique id/node in firebase for each concert within an event.

If a user enters that there are 3 concerts in a given event, I need my for loop to create a node and unique id for each concert then populate that node with the concert details (concertDetails).

Users enter the number of concerts in a text box called numberOfConcertsText.text.

Here's my code and database reference:

```
concertref = ref.child("Concerts").child(eid).childByAutoId()

if let concertInt = Int(numberOfConcertsText.text!) {

    for index in 1...concertInt {

     var concertDetails = ["concert name" : "concert \(index)"] as [String : Any]
     concertref.updateChildValues(concertDetails)

    } else { 
      print ("error")
    {
```

When the code runs, it only writes one node to firebase with the last value. So it loops like it's just overwriting each loop and writing the last one.

From what I've read in other examples I *think* this is because my database reference is established outside of the loop, so it's creating one node and then looping through that same reference each time? But I can't figure out how I get it to create a new node for each reference instead of reusing the same one?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you move `concertref` into for loop, it will create a brand new node for every index. childByAutoID() automatically constructs you a new node, you just need to set/update its value.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! I had tried to move it down earlier but I received an error. Which I think was because had two other references that I didn't move with it.

When I moved all of the references into my button method then moved the concertref into the loop, that did it. 

Thanks a bunch!